# Determine monthly values of timestamped records

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

I have a SQL table with the following schema:

```
fruit_id INT 
price    FLOAT
date     DATETIME
```

This table contains many records where the price of a given fruit is recorded at a given time. There may be multiple records in a single day, there may be

I would like to be able to fetch a list of prices for a single fruit over the last 12 months inclusive of the current month. So given a fruit_id of 2 and datetime of now(), what would the price values be for December, January, February, ... October, November?

Given the above requirements, **what strategy would you use to get this data**? Pure sql, fetch all prices and process in code?

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about min price, max price, average price, or something else?

Here's a quick query to get you started, which includes min, max, and average price for each month for fruit_id 2:

```
select left(date,7) as the_month, min(price),max(price),avg(price)
from fruit_price
where fruit_id = 2
and date >= concat(left(date_sub(curdate(), interval 11 month),7),'-01')
group by the_month;
```

Comment: OP says he wants results of single fruit over the last 12 months..this will give results for all months..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly from -

`I would like to be able to fetch a list of prices for a single fruit over the last 12 months inclusive of the current month. So given a fruit_id of 2 and datetime of now(), what would the price values be for December, January, February, ... October, November?`

You want the total price for every month for a single year based on the date and fruit_if you pass in.

So,this won't give all months of an year but all months which had a price for year..in case you want all months..you would need to create a dimdate table which will have all the dates...and then join with it..

```
    declare @passeddate=Now() --date to be calculated
    declare @fruit_id=2 --fruit id to be calculated
    Select 
          fruit_id as FruitId,
          Sum(price) as MonthPrice,
          Month(date)  as FruitMonth
    from SQL_Table 
    group by FruitMonth,FruitId  
    where fruit_id=@fruit_id and
    Year(date)=Year(@passeddate)
```

Comment: are you sure about this bit `@fruit_id='01/02/2010'`

Answer (score 0):

```
select month(date) as "Month", distinct(price) as "Unique Price" where fruit_id = 2 group by month(date);
```

I'd try to state as much as possible in SQL that does not require unindexed access to data because it's usually fast(er) than processing it with the application.

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely right: select month(date) as "Month", distinct(price) as "Unique Price" where fruit_id = 2 group by month(date);